# QBitArray size stays zero after trying to fill it with stream operator

Tags: qt, qbytearray

Why does the size of QBitArray stay zero? I am using Qt 5.0.2.

```
QByteArray bytes(4,'b'); // four bytes
QBitArray bits;
QDataStream stream(&bytes, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

stream >> bits;

qDebug() << bytes.size() << bits.size();
```

Comment: the output is "4 0"??

Comment: @UmNyobe: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading from a `QDataStream` it expects the data to be in a certain format, as described at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/datastreamformat.html.  In the case of streaming `QBitArray` this is:

> ```
> The array size (quint32)
> The array bits, i.e. (size + 7)/8 bytes
> ```

If this is not the case the operation will fail - you can check `QDataStream::status()` to detect errors.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you are right. For testing purposes I filled the QByteArray size*8 and byte per byte to a stream coupled with another buffer and then to QBitArray, which works. Of course, that is not very handy anymore...